# 1/2 Inch CSST vs 3/4 inch pipe for isolated 45 ft run from LNG Meter to 71000 total BTU stove?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, natural-gas

Adding NG stove to existing service.  Significant price difference in quotes.  What risk do we take going with the smaller diameter CSST over the pipe?  There will be four 90 degree turns over 45 foot run.  No intention of connecting additional appliances.  Could there be flow issues with the lower diameter CSST?

Comment: The instructions should say something about what to use as far as piping is concerned.  with a 45ft run, i'd be thinking pipe.

Comment: Why are you comparing 1/2 inch CSST to 3/4 inch pipe? Why not 3/4 inch CSST? The use of CSST means no 90 deg bends, so the 1/2 inch CSST should work?

Comment: Corrugated stainless tubing on that long of a run sounds crazy 1/2” I doubt it. CSST has friction losses well beyond pipe losses so yes there will be issues using small CSST. How will it be protected?